# Android referencing Asset folder images inside javascript file?

Tags: javascript, android

I have a webview setup in android which loads a local html file in my asset folder.

Inside this html file I reference local javascript files.

Inside these javascript files I need to use images inside my asset folder. How would I link to them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Myactivity extends Activity {

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String temp= "<html><head></head><body><img src=\"file:///android_asset/flower.png\"><p>Hello flower.</p></body></html>";
    WebView wb = new WebView(this);
    wb.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, temp, "text/html", "utf-8",null);
    setContentView(wb);


} 
}
```

//try this

Comment: It isn't this webview I am having trouble loading. It's the images inside the javascript that populate the webview.

Comment: please Share Some Code for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

You can access all files from assets folder as same as you would access files on a server - by relative paths.

To load /assets/www/images/logo.jpg from file /assets/www/index.html:

```
<img src="images/logo.jpg" />
```

Update:

in jQuery:

```
 $('#myLogo').attr('src', 'image/logo.jpg');
```

Comment: Well, there seems to be something wrong with my paths then.. if i had my js in one folder, and my images in another folder both under a root folder, how would I link to the image folder? Would it not just be /root/images/ex.png

Comment: If you have JS files in subfolder, you may need to 'jump up', e.g. if you have JS in /assets/www/js/script.js then use '../images/logo.jpg

Comment: ahh yes, my javascript took the image relative to the html file and not it self. Ok I think I'm fixed now. Thanks dude.